# Auto blank spacer program or application

Tags: tabs

Well, I recenely made some work on PHP and HTML, and I did not use the TAB thing to make blank spaces which make the code more readable and organized, and now it pisses me off. Anyone knows an effective way or any program where you can put your HTML or PHP and it makes all these spaces for you, making the code more organized? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a specific editor, some have "Beautify" features that will auto-tab your source.

In the mean time, you can try this: http://www.beautifyphp.com/